# I want to check if there is a specific key in the json object

Tags: arrays, json, delphi, json-value

I want to check if the JSON object has the key `"error"`. If it has, I want to "continue" the loop, otherwise the program can go to all the loop.

This is the JSON:

```json
[
    {
        "cenario": {
            "origem": "",
            "out": "SNC",
            "country": "",
        },
        "item": "0015963",
        "cod": "17894904009319",
        "nat_rec": null
    },
    {
        "item": "0012868",
        "error": "product unavailable",
        "status": "unavailable",
    }
]
```

How can I check if the object that I'm reading has the key `"error"` or not?

I tried:

```pascal
jValue.FindValue('error') // The problem it's going to search for all objects.
jValue.TryGetValue('error', jArray) // if it doesn't find the key in the index that it's searching at the moment, it breaks the application.
```

I'm doing:

```pascal
response:= IdHTTP.Get(url);

jValue:= TJsonObject.ParseJSONValue(response);

for x := 0 to 2 do
begin
    
  if jValue.TryGetValue('error', jvalue) then
  begin
    continue;
  end;

  memo.Lines.Add('cod_item :' + jValue.GetValue<string>('['+intToStr(x)+'].item'));
  memo.Lines.Add('cod: ' + jValue.GetValue<string>('['+intToStr(x)+'].cod'));
end;
```

Comment: Which JSON framework are you using? Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating how you are loading the JSON and how you are iterating/searching through it.

Comment: I'm not using any framework. Everything is native from delphi.

Comment: Well, then you are using Delphi's own [JSON framework](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/JSON) ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, `jValue` is pointing at a `TJSONArray`, so when you call `TryGetValue('error')` on it, you are looking for a field named `'error'` on the array itself, which obviously is not going to work. That would only work when called on a `TJONObject` instead.

You would need to include each object's index when querying for the `'error'` field on the array itself, eg:

```
response := IdHTTP.Get(url);

jValue := TJsonObject.ParseJSONValue(response);
try
  jArray := jValue as TJSONArray;
  for x := 0 to jArray.Count-1 do
  begin
    if jArray.FindValue('['+IntToStr(x)+'].error') = nil then
      continue;
    Memo.Lines.Add('cod_item :' + jArray.GetValue<string>('['+IntToStr(x)+'].item'));
    Memo.Lines.Add('cod: ' + jArray.GetValue<string>('['+IntToStr(x)+'].cod'));
  end;
finally
  jValue.Free;
end;
```

Alternatively, you can iterate the actual objects in memory instead of searching via paths, eg:

```
response := IdHTTP.Get(url);

jValue := TJsonObject.ParseJSONValue(response);
try
  jArray := jValue as TJSONArray;
  for x := 0 to jArray.Count-1 do
  begin
    jObj := jArray[x] as TJSONObject;
    if jObj.GetValue('error') = nil then
    begin
      Memo.Lines.Add('cod_item :' + jObj.GetValue('item').Value);
      Memo.Lines.Add('cod: ' + jObj.GetValue('cod').Value);
    end;
  end;
finally
  jValue.Free;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parse it to an array and iterate the array. The two functions HasValueAtObjectKey & GetValueAtObjectKey demonstrate two different ways of checking the object for the key.

```
program JsonTest;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.JSON;

const TEST_JSON = '[' +
                  '   {' +
                  '       "cenario": {' +
                  '           "origem": "",' +
                  '           "out": "SNC",' +
                  '           "country": ""' +
                  '       },' +
                  '       "item": "0015963",' +
                  '       "cod": "17894904009319",' +
                  '       "nat_rec": null' +
                  '   },' +
                  '   {' +
                  '       "item": "0012868",' +
                  '       "error": "product unavailable",' +
                  '       "status": "unavailable"' +
                  '   }' +
                  ']';

function HasValueAtObjectKey(AKeyName: String; AJsonObject: TJsonObject): Boolean;
var
  LValue: TJsonValue;
begin
  Result := AJsonObject.TryGetValue(AKeyName, LValue);
end;

function GetValueAtObjectKey(AKeyName: String; AJsonObject: TJsonObject; var AHasValue: Boolean): String;
begin
  try
    Result := AJsonObject.GetValue(AKeyName).Value;
    AHasValue := TRUE;
  except
    AHasValue := FALSE;
  end;
end;

begin
  try
    var LArray := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(TEST_JSON) as TJSONArray;
    try
      var i:=1;
      for var LArrayValue in  LArray do
      begin
        var LHasValue: Boolean;
        var LErroVal := ValueAtObjectKey('error', (LArrayValue As TJSONObject), LHasValue);
        if LHasValue then
          Writeln('Object ', i, ' Has error: ', LErroVal)
        else
          Writeln('Object ', i, ' Has no error: ');
          Writeln('Object ', i, ' HasValueAtObjectKey: ', HasValueAtObjectKey('error', (LArrayValue As TJSONObject)));
        Inc(i);
      end;
    finally
      LArray.Free;
    end;
    ReadLn;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

Comment: It would make more sense for `HasValueAtObjectKey()` to use `TJSONObject.Get()`, `TJONObject.Pairs[]`, or `TJSONObject.FindValue()` instead of `TJSONObject.TryGetValue()`, since the value is being discarded, so there is no point in retrieving it. Likewise with `GetValueAtObjectKey()`, then you can avoid the overhead of exception handling